# template struct as template class type

Tags: c++

```
  template<class T,class TV> struct CONJUGATE_GRADIENTS_HELPER{
      DEFORMABLE_OBJECT<T,TV>* deformable_object;
      int partition_id;
      T time,dt;
      T alpha,beta;
      ARRAY<TV>* dX_full;
      ARRAY<double> *S_dot_Q_partial,*rho_new_partial,*supnorm_partial;
  };

  typedef CONJUGATE_GRADIENTS_HELPER<T,TV> T_CG_HELPER;
  ARRAY<double> S_dot_Q_partial(particles.particle_ranges->m);
  ARRAY<T_CG_HELPER> helpers(particles.particle_ranges->m);

  for(int p=1;p<=particles.particle_ranges->m;p++){
          helpers(p).deformable_object=this;
          helpers(p).partition_id=p;
          helpers(p).time=time;
          helpers(p).beta=beta;
          helpers(p).S_dot_Q_partial=&S_dot_Q_partial;
  }
```

What do the brackets in helpers(p) stand for? How can we iterate through helpers since helpers is a single object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off goes the psychic answer, since I don't know what `ARRAY` exactly is...

It seems your `ARRAY` class template overloads the function call operator `operator()` instead of the index operator `operator[]`. Just use it as if those `()` brackets where normal array indexing brackets `[]`.
Also, your code clearly shows a way to iterate over `helpers` with the `for`-loop...

Anyway, for further help we need to see some code.

Answer (score 1):

`helpers` is an `ARRAY` where the first template parameter is `T_CG_HELPER`. This likely means it's an "ARRAY of T_CG_HELPERs".

You haven't shown us what the `ARRAY` class looks like, so it's impossible to know how to iterate over it. `helpers(p)` means "invoke the `operator()` function on `helpers`, passing `p` as the argument".